# Appium 1.7.1 with Crosswalk

Tags: android, python, macos, appium, crosswalk

I’ve noticed that crosswalk integration was added to appium back on may, but i’ve been having problems getting my test script to recognize the webview context once i added crosswalk to my project.

I want to be able to write tests using the webview instead of using the native context but have found it hard to configure and I haven’t been able to find any mentions of crosswalk configs within appium docs.

Here’s the added functionality’s commit https://github.com/appium/appium-android-driver/commit/11072c916b5384cf35b1d2782f2e75cf42967afd#diff-4a755e0b07ee6408ea73eb1395292bdb

So my question is, are there any special requirements i need to set in place or is the code still under work?

I’m working on Mac using android devices with:

- Appium 1.7.1
- Python 2.7.13
- Appium-Python-Client 0.24
- Crosswalk 23.53.589.4

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the new appium update already support crosswalk but the driver still not , this is why you still have problems . you can download this driver and just switch it in your appium files under appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win. 
also you will need the latest appium update (from last week)
https://github.com/piotrekkmt/chromedriver-appium